# How to elegantly represent a three dimensional array as a collection in Java?

Tags: java, collections

I was thinking about creating a List of Lists of Lists, but is this really the best way of doing this in Java? Would this create a lot of memory overhead for a huge 3D-array?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Often the elegant way is to create a class `Triplet` that contains 3 elements, and store them in some DS. If this is a good idea or not really depends on what is your actual goal.

Comment: And also - don't worry about the memory overhead - if it'll become a problem - fix it when it does. You should however worry about maintainability of your code and how easy it is to change things in it - and a List of Lists of Lists - isn't easy to maintain at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best structure here will depend heavily on how it is likely to be used.

Firstly, if the dimensions of your array reflect different types (e.g. an array of demographic data with age, income and region as dimensions) then it's a good idea to encapsulate each of these as an `enum` or `class` rather than try to encode in an `int` just for the purpose of indexing in an array. Things like EnumMap are very efficient in storage and access.

If it will be a sparse array (i.e. will have many null or empty values) then your best structure may be a Map from coordinates to value. In that case the size of the dimensions is irrelevant: the number of values is the only important thing.

On the other hand if the array has fixed size with all cells having a value then a traditional [ ][ ][ ] array could well be your most efficient mechanism.

However ultimately your design should naturally reflect your problem domain: it's usually a mistake to attempt to optimise for speed or memory early on. Solve those problems later when you know they really are problems. And when you do solve them make sure the optimised implementation details are hidden behind a well defined interface.

Comment: Sorry for only accepting this as an answer now. I ended up using a [][][] for storing coordinates of objects in 3D space.